# Space between frames using tkinter pack geometry manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to understand how pack works in tkinter.

I do the following sample code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('TEST')

frame1 = tk.Frame(window, height="90", background="red")
frame2 = tk.Frame(window, height="10", background="green")
frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, side=tk.TOP)
frame2.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1, side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.S)

window.mainloop()
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But if the windows is strecht, then an empty (grey) area appears between both frames. My expectation with the above code would be that the red frame would take all available space.

[image]

---

Edit: following Bryan's answer, this is the right code to get the required behaviour.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('TEST')

frame1 = tk.Frame(window, height="90", background="red")
frame2 = tk.Frame(window, height="10", background="green")
frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, side=tk.TOP)
frame2.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.S)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `expand`, that tells tkinter to give unallocated space to that widget. When you set `expand` to True on more than one widget, the unallocated space is divided between all of the widgets with that option set to True.

The [canonical documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm) says this:

> If a master window is so large that there will be extra space left over after all of its slaves have been packed, then the extra space is distributed uniformly among all of the slaves for which the -expand option is set.+

What you are seeing is that half of the unallocated space is given to the top widget, and half is given to the bottom widget. Because the `fill` option is "both" for the top widget, the widget will fill all of the space allocated to it. However, because you specified a fill of "x", the extra space in the y axis goes unfilled.

For a very precise description of how the packer works, see [The Packer Algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26) in the tcl/tk man pages for [pack](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm)

Comment: Thanks, this is a clear explanation on why this was not working.